# make html in sphinx not working due to company policy

Tags: python, python-sphinx

The company I work for has a policy to ensure that all batch files are run from C:\LocalData\Apps and my python code is stored in a separate directory and drive i.e. P:\mhooper\python\projectX.

In cmd when I run `sphinx-quickstart` and the appropriate prompts afterwards I can see the make.bat, conf.py and the rst files that are created.

I now want to run in cmd `make html` command.

Is there any way to move the batch file to the directory to successfully create the html file? Do I have to move all the rst files also? Very new to sphinx but looks to be a good tool.

Comment: If the IT policies at my company were so short-sighted as to prevent getting my work done, I would find another company.